# epub files does not downloadable [ANDROID]

Tags: java, android, epub

I've set set files to localhost an set the `href` links for the epub files ..

```
<a href="more-utopia.epub" target="_blank"> more-utopia </a><br>
```

and I've try to browse from my custom web view .. but when I click to download the link , it appears no download .. and open the file in the browser with custom web view.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("http://10.0.2.2/epub");
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebView());  
}   

class myWebView extends WebViewClient{
    @Override
       public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        url = "http://10.0.2.2/epub/";
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

What  I want to do is to download the files and want to set path the download location to user selected location .

Any helpful tips are humbly welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is set up to prevent people from downloading anything. Every time they click the link, you have them load the original Web page again. Try using `setDownloadListener()` on your `WebView` instead. Or, change your `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` to do what your question says you want it to do.